# Box and whisker plot looks significant but paper says it is not?

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I am reading this paper ["Long-term vitamin D treatment decreases human uterine leiomyoma size in a xenograft animal model"](https://www.fertstert.org/article/S0015-0282(19)32372-6/fulltext) and one of their plots looks strange to me.

[image]

According to the paper, caspase 3 expression is not significantly different between the control and vit D 1 ug/kg/day group. I find this confusing since it certainly *looks* significant, especially compared to other results on the same scale that they have found to be significant.

[image]

I'm wondering how this might be true that the results are not statistically significant. If anyone has any insight it's much appreciated. And sorry in advance, my statistics knowledge is fairly limited.

Comment: How are you assessing significance by looking at boxplots?  Unless they are strikingly different, this is impossible to do, because significance in an ANOVA depends (among other things) on (a) data counts; (b) means, and (c) standard deviations, yet boxplots show *none* of these quantities.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a better answer from someone more versed in stats but here's my take.

From the paper:
"For the analysis of Ki67, cell density, and **Western blot experiments**, analysis of variance and Kruskal-Wallis tests were carried out to analyze data from short- and long-term treatments, respectively"

The 21 day (short term) data was tested by ANOVA (test of equality of means; parametric and therefore constrained) and the 60 day (long term) data was tested by Kruskal-Wallis (comparison of mean ranks; non-parametric by default).

My limited understanding of Kruskal-Wallis is that it is sometimes difficult to understand the significance results without knowledge of the distributions in the data, which can be severely misrepresented graphically.

Comment: I didn’t read the paper, but something about changing statistical test (ANOVA to KW) is sending me through the roof.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Any idea why they might have used different tests?

Comment: We could only speculate. One guess would be that the short term data met the parametric assumptions of ANOVA (eg normally distributed residuals) but the long term data did not, so a different test was used. If this was the case, better practice would have been to use the non parametric test for both groups. It is possible that they did initially use KW for both groups but didn't get any significance, which could motivate a person to change tests